# Version control and updating of AssemblyInfo files

Tags: c#, .net, svn, version-control, merge

I'm maintaining an application of (mostly) C# code using subversion. I'm wondering what is the best practice for when and where to update the AssemblyInfo.cs files to reflect the version number of the product as it ships.

Let's say I have a trunk, and some maintenance branches for previous versions and tags to tag each release when it happens.

If I update the AssemblyInfo files in the branch or trunk before tagging (this is my current approach), it means I can look down the log of that branch to see when releases happened which is quite useful, but it gives me spurious merge conflicts when merging between branches. For instance say I make a bug fix in the version 4 branch which updates version 4.7 to 4.8; when I try to merge that fix into the version 5 branch, the AssemblyInfo is bound to conflict.

I have also considered updating the AssemblyInfo files in the tag itself. this avoids the merge conflict problem but means you can't see the releases when looking down the history of trunk or a maintenance branch, and it also seems to violate the principle that a tag should be read-only.

From what I gather, some people like to update the AssemblyInfo files on-the-fly during the build process, and not store them in SVN at all. Although on the face of it, it seems like a good idea to automate the version numbering, I think I'd feel a lot more comfortable if the AssemblyInfo files are checked in immediately prior to performing the build so that there is a direct correlation between the version number on the assembly and the source it came from.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing experience: I do this on the build server *only* in the automated fashion. I've configured it once and not touching it any more, apart from infrequently incrementing major and minor version. Here is an outline:

- AssemblyInfo.cs is committed to source control
- AssemblyInfo.cs is not manually changed by developers
- Build server picks up source on any change to source control
- Build server changes AssemblyInfo automatically
- Build server produces artefacts with correct version
- When I tag/branch I create a tag with the build version from Build Server

Modern build servers will have features that will automate the whole process of changing this file, for example see [AssemblyInfo patcher in TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/AssemblyInfo+Patcher)

The version strategy I use is:

```
major.minor.build_number.svn_revision_number
```

Where `major` and `minor` are manually hardcoded as configuration parameter on the build server. `build_number` is automatically incremented by the build server. `svn_revision_number` is picked up from the svn commit number.

Comment: Thanks for this useful insight. can you tell me, does the build server check in the AssemblyInfo files into the source code repository when it increments them? From what I saw on the AssemblyInfo Patcher page, it reverts them after the build. I would have thought it's very useful to be able to directly link the binaries to the source version by having the assemblyinfo files checked in with the correct version numbers.

Comment: @Andy that is a good point. To answer your question: no, build server does not check in the patched file back to source control. Effectively, that file always stays on 1.0.0.0 version in svn. However, when your binaries are build, they will be the version set by the build server, for example `2.3.345.932`. From this version I can tell that it is version `2.3`. It has been build on the build server `345` times and **the source control revision number is 932**. So the last number tells me exactly what's the svn rev#, so I can go back to my tags or log and see what changes were there. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks that is a very interesting observation. Of course I don't need to put the assemblyInfo files into svn control if the svn revision number is in the assemblies.

Comment: @Andy I think the file is required for the assembly patcher as a template, but I am not 100% sure.